# Build automation to create a jar file with differences only

Tags: java, ant, build, automation, hudson

At my current company we build major releases about twice a year, and throughout the year, when bugs are fixed or new enhancements added, we build service packs to release.

- A service pack would basically be a .jar file that is dumped onto the clients machine, and since it is first on the classpath, that is then the code that will execute. (If you do not know what I am talking about - sorry, this might be old school).
- The jar file contains only the changed class files and it is normally assembled by hand, by the developer on the job.

I am using hudson for above mentioned steps. If it is possible to specify that hudson to look at two revisions and put the differences between them to a service pack (class files into a sp.jar). This would enable us to automate our deployment of enhancement or bug fixes and it would definitely have added advantage.

If anyone know of such functionality or setup, could you please share your online resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ant script you can achieve the output:
See some tool which can help you.

[clirr](http://clirr.sourceforge.net/)

```
java -jar clirr-core-0.6-uber.jar -o OLD.jar -n NEW.jar
```

Or [JAPICC](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker)

```
japi-compliance-checker OLD.jar NEW.jar
```

Or PkgDiff

```
pkgdiff OLD.jar NEW.jar
```

Comment: Hi Sanjit, thanks for your reply. If I look at your commands above, it seems that these tools look at differences between two different jar files. I would like for a tool that looks at two different subversion revisions, and then build a corresponding jar file...

Comment: If i have understood your problem correctly. 
what VCS you use if it is SVN then you can use `svn diff -r 11390(revision old):8979(revision new) pathtofile`.

Comment: I use subversion, yes. Thank you! I think somehow i need to keep track of the versions, and if a certain version was released to the client, we need to remember those details somehow.